# SinglePredictionBands versus MeanPredictionBands from NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

From my Statistics lectures I know the term confidence and prediction interval, whereas the confidence interval is smaller than the prediction interval. If I plot the mean and single prediction bands with the same confidence level in *Mathematica*, than the mean prediction band is smaller than the single prediction band interval.

Anyone who can explain me what are the differences between the `“SinglePredictionBands”` and `“MeanPredictionBands”` which are standard properties from `NonlinearModelFit`?
 Or is it just a different terminology for confidence and prediction interval used by *Mathematica*? If no it would be useful if someone can tell me which properties I have to apply for the confidence and the prediction interval.

Answer (score 3):

Citing [this Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MeanAndSinglePredictionBandsForANonlinearModel/) by Darren Glosemeyer (Wolfram Research):

> Single prediction bands incorporate both the variation in parameter
>   estimates and the overall variation in response values, while the mean
>   confidence bands incorporate only the variation in parameter
>   estimates. As a result, single prediction bands are wider than mean
>   prediction bands for the same confidence level. Mean prediction bands
>   also exhibit more variation in width.

Also from [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2010/Jun/msg00409.html) MathGroups post:

> The method used is very briefly described near the end of
>
> http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html
>
> "Tabular results for confidence intervals are given by 
>   "MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTable" and 
>   "SinglePredictionConfidenceIntervalTable". These results are analogous
>   to those for linear models obtained via LinearModelFit, again with 
>   first-order approximations used for the design matrix.
>
> "MeanPredictionBands" and "SinglePredictionBands" give functions of
>   the  predictor variables."
>
> The bands use the same formulas as the confidence intervals. The
>   method  is the same for 2, 3, or more parameters.
>
> Darren Glosemeyer Wolfram Research

One can also find useful this blog post: "[Two kinds of Prediction bands](http://rip94550.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/regression-1-%E2%80%93-two-kinds-of-prediction-bands/)."

Answer (score 0):

- *SinglePredictionBands* - confidence bands based on single observations
- *MeanPredictionBands* - confidence bands for mean predictions

Directly from the help centre under the *Details and Options* submenu
[Link](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html)